# Why does our ownership chain break in T-SQL stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have two stored procedures in the same Azure SQL DB, `[a].[doA]` and `[b].[doB]`

User has `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `EXECUTE` on schema `[a]`, and nothing on other schemas.

All db schemas have owner `[dbo]`

Both procedures do selects, inserts, updates on other schemas, and both run dynamic queries on other schemas with `EXEC @sql` syntax (we don't use sp_excutesql, as it breaks the ownership chain).

`[a].[doA]` also calls `[b].[doB]` in some cases, and in those cases the ownership chain seems to break in the dynamic sql part of `[b].[doB]`, we receive an error when executing the dynamic query there: *The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'table', database 'db', schema 'c'*

We are very surprised, as ownership chain works in all other cases, both `[a].[doA]` executing dynamic sql on schema `[c]`, and `[b].[doB]` running queries on schema `[c]`.

Why is this the case? How can we prevent it?

We already tried the following workarounds, both didn't work:

- we granted user `EXECUTE` on schema `[b]`
- we moved `[doB]` to schema `[a]`

**Edit:** I do understand that `EXEC @sql` is supposed to break the ownership chain just like `sp_executesql`, but in our environment, whenever we use `sp_executesql`, our ownership chain breaks, and when we use `EXEC @sql`, it only breaks in this one case

Comment: Dynamic sql already breaks ownership chain as far as i know. There's nothing special about sp_executesql. Perhaps user piggybacks on some other rights so it sometimes works anyway. Try to create a simple reduction of the problem so it's possible to script and run it

Comment: Dynamic SQL breaks the chain regardless of the syntax used to execute the T-SQL batch. Consider signing the proc with a certificate based on a user with the needed permissions.

Comment: I recommend the excellent reading https://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html , check the TOC to maybe find your proc's weak spot

Comment: Alternatively you could create the procs with EXECUTE AS OWNER, instead of the default which is AS CALLER.  Then dynamic SQL will work.

Comment: I don't know what's special in our environment, but whenever we use sp_executesql, our ownership chain breaks, and when we use EXEC @sql, it only breaks in this one case

Comment: Then there's something *else* going on, @TamásBárász . Both versions work the same way for ownership chaining, as I demonstrated; perhaps you should post a (new) question with specifics and a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have changed `[b].[doB]` to `EXECUTE AS OWNER`, and it works now.

Thanks [David Browne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7297700/) for the suggestion!

Thanks [Thom A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/) for your well researched answer, we ended up going in another direction!

Thanks for everyone suggesting to use `sp_executesql`! I do agree that it is a good practice, and would normally always use it, but in our case (I also don't understand why) it causes permission problems. As the dinamic queries only need a numeric parameter at runtime, in this special case we decided that `EXEC @sql` was an acceptable solution.

Comment: `EXEC @SQL` is something different; that doesn't execute a dynamic batch, but a dynamic procedure.

Answer (score 1):

> both run dynamic queries on other schemas with EXEC @sql syntax (we don't use sp_excutesql, as it breaks the ownership chain).

As has been mentioned in the comments, this statement is not true. Both `EXEC(@Variable)` and `EXEC sys.sp_executesql` break chains. Using the syntax `EXEC(@Variable)` is, in my opinion, a bad habit. You can't parametrise a deferred statement when executed with the syntax `EXEC(@Variable)`, but you can when using `sys.sp_executesql`. You should *always* be using `sys.sp_executesql`. As a result, I ***strongly*** suggest you fix your procedures to switch to `sys.sp_executesql` so that you can properly parametrise your statements.

Once you fix that, then one solution would be to use certificates. This is a *simplified* example; you may well want to use a password for your certificates, and/or create the certificate from a file.

Firstly, let's set up a test environment with something similar to what you have:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (ID int, SomeString varchar(10));
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable
VALUES(1,'abc'),
      (2,'def');
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.SomeProc @ID int AS
BEGIN
    SELECT SomeString
    FROM dbo.SomeTable
    WHERE ID = 1;
END;
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.AnotherProc @ID int, @SchemaName sysname = N'dbo', @TableName sysname AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
            @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT SomeString' + @CRLF +
               N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + @CRLF +
               N'WHERE ID = 1;';

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@ID int',@ID;
END;
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.BadProc @ID int, @SchemaName sysname = N'dbo', @TableName sysname AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
            @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

    SET @SQL = CONCAT(N'SELECT SomeString',@CRLF,
                      N'FROM ',QUOTENAME(@SchemaName),N'.',QUOTENAME(@TableName),@CRLF,
                      N'WHERE ID = ', @ID,';'); --Whoop whoop! Injection vulnerability! Whoop whoop!

    EXEC (@SQL);
END;
GO

CREATE USER SomeUser WITHOUT LOGIN;
GRANT EXEC ON dbo.SomeProc TO SomeUser;
GRANT EXEC ON dbo.AnotherProc TO SomeUser;
GRANT EXEC ON dbo.BadProc TO SomeUser;
GO
```

So we have a table with some data in. We also 3 procedures, one non-dynamic, 2 dynamic (using `sys.sp_executesql` and `EXEC(@Variable)`). Finally we have a `USER` that has permissions to `EXECUTE` all those procedures, but no permissions on the table.

Let's try `EXEC`ing those procedures:

```sql
EXECUTE AS USER = 'SomeUser';
GO

EXEC dbo.SomeProc @ID = 1; --Works;
GO
EXEC dbo.AnotherProc @ID = 1, @TableName = N'SomeTable'; --Fails;
GO
EXEC dbo.BadProc @ID = 1, @TableName = N'SomeTable'; --Fails;
GO
REVERT;
GO
```

No surprise, we get a result from the first `EXEC` but the latter 2 both return same error:

> Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 52
> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'SomeTable', database 'Sandbox', schema 'dbo'.

So we can confirm that the error for the break in the chain occurs for *both* methods of dynamic SQL. Let's throw the bad procedure in the bin then:

```sql
DROP PROC dbo.BadProc;
```

Now let's create a certificate. To repeat, this is **simplified**; for more details on certificates read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-certificate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). Anyway, firstly create the `CERTIFICATE`, to create a `USER` from it and then grant that `USER` some permissions:

```sql
CREATE CERTIFICATE SomeCert WITH SUBJECT = N'Allow SELECT on dbo for Procedures'; --If you don't have a master key this will fail; create one.
GO
CREATE USER CertUser FROM CERTIFICATE SomeCert;
GO
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::dbo TO CertUser; --Allowing on all of dbo; you may well want to be more specific
```

Now what we need to do is sign the dynamic procedure; this will mean that the permissions of the certificate will be accessible to someone executing the procedure, however, the procedure is still run under the context of the caller (often important).

```sql
ADD SIGNATURE TO dbo.AnotherProc BY CERTIFICATE SomeCert; --If you passworded the cert, you'll need to pass that too
```

Now we can try executing the procedures again, and it'll work without issue:

```sql
EXECUTE AS USER = 'SomeUser';
GO
EXEC dbo.SomeProc @ID = 2; --Works;
GO
EXEC dbo.AnotherProc @ID = 2, @TableName = N'SomeTable'; --Works;
GO
REVERT;
GO
```

---

Clean up:

```sql
DROP PROC dbo.AnotherProc;
DROP PROC dbo.SomeProc;
DROP USER CertUser;
DROP CERTIFICATE SomeCert;
DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;
DROP USER SomeUser;
```

Comment: While it's probably called out in the documentation, module signing comes with the overhead of needing to re-sign any time the module is changed. So if you, in this case, alter the procedure, the existing signature is dropped and will get those permission errors until it's signed again. Related, it's *by design* that the signature is dropped so that such a module doesn't become a Trojan Horse for malicious code.

Comment: So much overhead and micro-managing... it boggles the mind.

Comment: I wouldn't say certificates are micro managing, nor cause a obvious overhead, @TT. .

Comment: Perhaps, @TT. , you could provide some kind of citation that denotes that certificates have a lot of overhead, as it (appears) you feel this answer is not helpful/useful it would be useful to understand for many why you feel that the certificates are bad.

Comment: We're talking about another sort of overhead, I'm not talking about performance but about having to manage the certificates for a granularity that is rarely needed (in my experience). I've resorted to "EXECUTE AS OWNER" myself in those cases, which appears to me as boilerplate code. I assume that in some scenarios the certificates have value, I'm wondering of all real-world cases how much of a percentage.

Comment: The main benefit of certificates I actually mention in the answer, @TT . , that the procedure is still executed under the context of the caller. When it's important knowing who did what, this is key. Also for coss database queries `EXECUTE AS OWNER` may well not be an option, as th owner is local to the database and so would not extend permissions to the other database.