# Permission error when running dynamic SQL but not when using a normal statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a stored procedure that gives a permissions error when trying to do an `UPDATE` using dynamic SQL under user `HandheldServiceAcct`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spHandheldTest] 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000) = 'UPDATE [TableName] SET [Order Quantity] = 1 WHERE [ID] = 1' 
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql 
END
```

I then execute it like this:

```
execute as login = 'HandheldServiceAcct';
exec spHandheldTest
```

but I get this error:

> The UPDATE permission was denied on the object 'TableName', database 'DB', schema 'dbo'.

The same `UPDATE` statement works when I **don't** use dynamic SQL.

Why is this? What would I have to do to allow this dynamic `UPDATE` to work?

Comment: Why are you using dynamic in the first place? From what you posted there is no need for dynamic sql here at all.

Comment: @SeanLange it's a simplified version of what my stored procedure actually does. I am considering rewriting it to not use dynamic sql, but for now I was curious as to how to make it work, even if it is not recommended practice.

Comment: which rights has your user

Comment: Regarding why, permissions are not checked with static SQL in a proc as long the objects involved have the same owner (ownership chaining). Permissions are checked with dynamic SQL, requiring permissions on those objects in addition to execute permission on the proc. One way to avoid the permission issue with dynamic SQL is to sign the proc with a cert based on a user with the needed permisions.

Comment: Dynamic sql leaves the rights scope that the procedure has assigned to itself, so that's by design

Comment: If you don't want to bother with certificates (but they are usually pretty neat) and you don't do any cross-db stuff, you might be able to get away with setting procedure as 'execute as owner'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does our ownership chain break in T-SQL stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77557245/why-does-our-ownership-chain-break-in-t-sql-stored-procedures/77557721#77557721) (I'm sure there are other candidates, just this one is in recent memory).

Comment: @ThomA is a certificate commonly used? I've never heard of it before today and I don't understand why to use or when to use it

Comment: I find them more common for cross database solutions, but they can be used in single database solutions too (normally when you need to maintain the context of the user running the code).